# Could not load type 'System.Data.Services.Providers.IDataServiceUpdateProvider' from assembly 'System.Data.Services, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

Tags: 2010

When I tried to see this service
http://win-j8t24f4b519/_vti_bin/listdata.svc

I got this error
What should I do?

Comment: Are you accessing the webservice anonymously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that I had not installed Ado.net data services!

Comment: Please inform if you did anything else to fix this issue besides installing the update. Did you reboot? Is this the update you installed? https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22734

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to check is to see if the assembly actually is in the GAC (C:\windows\assembly).